# How to fix Class not found error while making POST request?

Tags: laravel, postman

In api.php I've described some routes. GET method works. Can't tell the same about POST method.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\UserUnfo;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) 
{
   return $request->user();
});

Route::get('/person', function() {
   $person = [
        'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
        'name' => 'me'
    ];
    return $person;
});

Route::post('/person', function(Request $request) {
    $userInfo = UserInfo::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'ip' => $request->input('ip')
    ]);
    return $userInfo;
});
```

In web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

The error I've got

```
Class &#039;UserInfo&#039; not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong model it's spell mistake.

```
use App\UserUnfo;
```

To

```
use App\UserInfo;
```